# Why my espeak-ng program doesn't say anything?

Tags: c++, espeak

I want to pass a string to espeak-ng and it reads my string by sound!

I searched and found this program and did a little modification to change it to English from Italian(under the commented lines), but didn't work:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <espeak-ng/speak_lib.h>



espeak_POSITION_TYPE position_type;
espeak_AUDIO_OUTPUT output;
char *path=NULL;
int Buflength = 500, Options=0;
void* user_data;
t_espeak_callback *SynthCallback;
espeak_PARAMETER Parm;



//char Voice[] = {"lt+klatt2"};
 char Voice[] = {"English"};

char text[30] = {"this is a english test"};
unsigned int Size,position=0, end_position=0, flags=espeakCHARS_AUTO, *unique_identifier;




int main(int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{
    output = AUDIO_OUTPUT_PLAYBACK;
    int I, Run = 1, L;    
    espeak_Initialize(output, Buflength, path, Options ); 
    espeak_SetVoiceByName(Voice);
    //const char *langNativeString = "lt"; //Default to US English
    const char *langNativeString = "en"; //Default to US English
    espeak_VOICE voice;
    memset(&voice, 0, sizeof(espeak_VOICE)); // Zero out the voice first
    voice.languages = langNativeString;
    //voice.name = "klatt";
    voice.name = "US";
    voice.variant = 2;
    voice.gender = 1;
    espeak_SetVoiceByProperties(&voice);
    Size = strlen(text)+1;    
    printf("Saying  '%s'",text);
    espeak_Synth( text, Size, position, position_type, end_position, flags,
    unique_identifier, user_data );
    espeak_Synchronize( );
    printf("\n:Done\n"); 
    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem?

It compiles without errors and makes `speaks` as executable file but when I try `./speaks` the result is:

```
Saying  'this is a english test'
:Done
```

Without voice!

EDIT: I asked my question in `gitub` and somebody said:

> The path parameter of espeak_Initialize needs to point to the
>   espeak-ng-data directory, or its parent directory. Alternatively, you
>   can set the ESPEAK_DATA_PATH environment variable to point to that
>   directory.

So I did add this line `ESPEAK_DATA_PATH=/usr/local/share/espeak-ng-data` to `/etc/environment` file but nothing happened!

Also I tried to change the path variable of the code to this(as I know the address is true) `char *path="/usr/local/share/espeak-ng-data"` but no voice again!

Comment: Did you [install pcaudiolib for audio output](https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng#building)?

Comment: @sehe: Sorry, I didn't get any notification about your comments! No, I didn't. I will install it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, trying this out you need to first build & install libpcaudio.

Then you configure & build espeak.

Next, when you run, you might need to specify the library paths:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/espeak-ng/src/.libs/:/usr/local/lib ./sotest
```

This then notified me of a problem:

```
Error processing file '/usr/local/share/espeak-ng-data/phontab': No such file or directory.
```

This tells me that libespeak-ng wants to be installed, due to hardcoded paths (of course the path itself can be modified using `./configure --prefix=` etc.)

I personally found that I had to do the LD_LIBRARY_PATH trick during building of all library artifacts, and had to run make many times in succession until finally it didn't report more errors.

> All this indicates that project maintenance is not very good. I've seen several segfaults even along the way.

After finally successfully doing

```
sudo make install
```

Your test program finally runs and makes the expected sound.

Comment: Sidenote: all of this already worked out of the box by just replacing `espeak-ng` with `espeak` in the include line and using `sudo apt-get install libespeak{1,-dev}`. You might want to stick to `libespeak` for this reason.

Comment: I did install `libpcaudio` and `./configure make make install` the `espeak-ng` again and compiled my code again without errors, but my program only gives me the text results not sound!

Comment: whats the meaning of this line `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/espeak-ng/src/.libs/:/usr/local/lib ./sotest ` ? what is `./sotest `? is it your program's name? did you put it inside `/etc/environment` ?

Comment: [LD_LIBRARY_PATH](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html#AEN80), `./sotest` was my test program, I did not put "it" (? anything) in `/etc/environment`

Comment: Whats the meaning of `{1,-dev}` ?

Comment: @Hasani sorry for late response, it's bash-style shell expansion. E.g. `abc{de,fg}` expands to `abcde abcfg`